# Interpolating an Expression into an Expression

Tags: metaprogramming, julia

I want to build a constructor with keyword arguments inside of a macro, and the first keyword argument needs to be for an expression. I am having trouble putting that expression into the expression. Here's what I mean. Say I have a type

```
type Test
  ex
end
```

which holds an expression. I want to make a constructor where `origex = :(a * b)` is the default from a keyword argument. I tried

```
@eval :(Test(ex=$origex) = Test(origex))
```

But if you look at the expression that makes:

```
Test(ex=a * b) = begin  # console, line 1:
    Test(origex)
end
```

you see that it won't work because the `a*b` needs to still be an expression. So I tried

```
@eval :(Test(ex=:($origex)) = Test(origex))
```

but this has the odd expression

```
Test(ex=$(Expr(:quote, :($(Expr(:$, :origex)))))) = begin  # console, line 1:
    Test(origex)
end
```

which also won't `eval`. Instead I need to get

```
Test(ex=:(a * b)) = begin  # console, line 1:
    Test(origex)
end
```

as the expression to eval, but I don't know how to get that expression into an expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following is what you want. You seem to have had a few mistakes:

```
julia> type Test
         ex::Expr
       end

julia> orig_ex = :(a + b)
:(a + b)

julia> new_ex = Meta.quot(orig_ex)
:($(Expr(:quote, :(a + b))))

julia> code = :( Test(; ex=$new_ex) = Test(ex) )
:(Test(; ex=$(Expr(:quote, :(a + b)))) = begin  # REPL[4], line 1:
            Test(ex)
        end)

julia> eval(code)
Test

julia> Test()
Test(:(a + b))
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked beautifully. What exactly is `Meta.quot`, and why is it different than :(orig_ex)?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas `Meta.quot(ex)` is simply `Expr(:quote, ex)`: `julia> ex = :(a + b); @assert Meta.quot(ex) == Expr(:quote, ex)`

Comment: Meta.quot adds another level of quoting. As you found, when you interpolate, just using :(orig_ex) isn't enough to keep the quoting. These things are pretty tricky to get right, in my experience!