# Interpolating an expression into an expression inside of a quote

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, julia

This question [builds off of a previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737199/interpolating-an-expression-into-an-expression) which was for building expressions from expressions inside of of a macro. However, things got a little trucker when quoting the whole expression. For example, I want to build the expression :(name=val). The following:

```
macro quotetest(name,val)
  quote
    nm = Meta.quot($(QuoteNode(name)))
    v = Meta.quot($(QuoteNode(val)))
    println(nm); println(typeof(nm))
    println(v); println(typeof(val))
  end
end

@quotetest x 5 # Test case: build :(x=5)
```

prints out

```
:x
Expr
$(Expr(:quote, 5))
Expr
```

showing that I am on the right path: nm and val are the expressions that I want inside of the quote. However, I can't seem to apply the previous solution at this point. For example,

```
macro quotetest(name,val)
  quote
    nm = Meta.quot($(QuoteNode(name)))
    v = Meta.quot($(QuoteNode(val)))
    println(nm); println(typeof(nm))
    println(v); println(typeof(v))
    println(:($(Expr(:(=),$(QuoteNode(nm)),$(QuoteNode(val))))))
  end
end
```

fails, saying `nm is not defined`. I tried just interpolating without the `QuoteNode`, escaping the interpolation `$(esc(nm))`, etc. I can't seem to find out how to make it build the expression.

Comment: `macro qtest(name,val) :(Expr(:(=),$(Meta.quot(name)),$(Meta.quot(val)))) end`. Does this return the desired expression? In the question the quote nesting seems higher than is needed (`quote` then `quot` then `:()` then `QuoteNode`... with some `$`s peppered).

Comment: While building the expression directly works for the simple case shown, it's much harder to generalize. You can build a macro which produces an output which will work at the REPL and be easy to test, and then turn it into something that works in functions by quoting it and interpolating everything correctly. I find that much easier than incrementally building a large expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using `$` signs more than you need to. Is this what you're looking for?

```
julia> macro quotetest(name,val)
           quote
               expr = :($$(QuoteNode(name)) = $$(QuoteNode(val)))
               println(expr)
               display(expr)
               println(typeof(expr))
           end
       end
@quotetest (macro with 1 method)

julia> @quotetest test 1
test = 1
:(test = 1)
Expr
```